# How to desable autoformating code when save in vscode using ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code

It might be a silly question, but I can't find the option in VScode using Ubuntu, to disable the autoformating option when saving. When I save my project, VScode reformats my code from what the programs things works better, but since I am sharing my project with another developer, that makes his job more difficult and I need to turn off the autoformating option. I dont have the package called "prettier".

Thanks.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting#automatically-formatting-code-in-vs-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `File > View > Command Pallette` or press `Strg+Shift+P`

Search for `Open Settings (JSON)`

Inside `settings.json` go to `"[dart]"` and look for `editor.formatOnSave` and set it to `false`

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Disable format on save in settings

`"editor.formatOnSave": false`